# laravel download function returns empty file

Tags: laravel, download, response

This laravel code downloads the file but its contents are empty

```
$doc = Document::find($id);
$filePath = Storage::path($doc->path);
$header = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
return response()->download($filePath, $doc->name, $header);
```

Comment: dd($doc->path) and check what you get.also where is the location of path files stored

Comment: return Storage::download($doc->path); also you can do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage download.Make sure `$doc->path` return full path of storage folder or if returns only file name then you have to append it before filename

```
$doc = Document::find($id);
return Storage::download($doc->path);
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Comment: Files are stored in storage/app/documents.
Tried above code still my file contents are empty

Comment: Storage::download('documents/file2.pdf'); this is an example

Comment: also what you get in $doc->path